# Enumerable inside struct or inside class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, enums, struct

i have a doubt about a best practice...
I have a bunch of enumerables inside my project and i dont want that they be separated, so my idea is to have one only class (or struct) with all the enumerables inside.. is that a good practice? If that is a good practice.. what is better? put all the enums inside a class or inside a struct?

Something like this:

```
public class (or struct) Enumerables{

    public enum Enum1{a, b, c}
    public enum Enum2{d, e, f}

}
```

I hope you can help me with this.
Thanks!

Comment: These are actually called "enumerations", not "enumerables" - those are something totally different.

Comment: *Why* don't you want them to be separated? Best practice dictates SOLID principles, having all enumerations in a class violates these. Namespaces can be used to logically group your enums.

Comment: The enumerable word is my mistake.. my English seems to be not so good :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum`s are **Enumerations**, not Enumerables.

There's also no need to isolate them in their own class. Just leave them as needed (they really act as a type of their own anyway). If they're logically related, you can group them into their own namespace.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to group them together, the usual approach is to put them in the same namespace. Put them in a class if they're only useful in relation to that class, but don't create a class just to contain them: that's what namespaces are for...

Answer (score 0):

You gain nothing from putting them into a a class or struct. In fact you add an extra complexity to your code. I suggest you to a separate namespace in order to structure your project.